# Scraping Address Information Using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape address information from https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address-iframe. I have a script that searches for the given address in its parameters. When I look at the website itself, one can see various fields like Carrier Route.

Using 3301 South Greenfield Rd Gilbert, AZ 85297 as a hypothetical example, when one goes to the page manually, one can see the Carrier Route: R109.

I am having trouble, however, finding the carrier route on Selenium to scrape it. Does have any recommendations for how to find the Carrier Route for any given address?

Starting code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
address = "3301 South Greenfield Rd Gilbert, AZ 85297\n"
url = 'https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address-iframe'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("lookup-select-button").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("lookup-select").find_element_by_id("address-freeform").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("freeform-address").send_keys(address)
# Find Carrier Route here
```

Comment: You can use just `requests` module to get the information. If you want I can post example.

Comment: I could answer you, but I see you don't accept answers.... So, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.execute_script` to provide input for the fields and to click the submission button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address-iframe')
s = '3301 South Greenfield Rd Gilbert, AZ 85297'
a, a1 = s.split(' Rd ')
route = d.execute_script(f'''
   document.querySelector('#address-line1').value = '{a}'
   document.querySelector('#city').value = '{(j:=a1.split())[0][:-1]}'
   document.querySelector('#state').value = '{j[1]}'
   document.querySelector('#zip-code').value = '{j[2]}'
   document.querySelector('#submit-request').click()
   return document.querySelector('#us-street-metadata li:nth-of-type(2) .answer.col-sm-5.col-xs-3').textContent
''')
```

Output:

```
'R109'
```

To get a full display of all the parameter data, you can use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
... #selenium driver source here
cols = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').select('#us-street-output div')
data = {i.h4.text:{b.select_one('span:nth-of-type(1)').get_text(strip=True)[:-1]:b.select_one('span:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)
         for b in i.select('ul li')} for i in cols}
print(data)
print(data['Metadata']['Congressional District'])
```

Output:

```
{'Metadata': {'Building Default': 'default', 'Carrier Route': 'R109', 'Congressional District': '05', 'Latitude': '33.291248', 'Longitude': '-111.737427', 'Coordinate Precision': 'Rooftop', 'County Name': 'Maricopa', 'County FIPS': '04013', 'eLOT Sequence': '0160', 'eLOT Sort': 'A', 'Observes DST': 'default', 'RDI': 'Commercial', 'Record Type': 'S', 'Time Zone': 'Mountain', 'ZIP Type': 'Standard'}, 'Analysis': {'Vacant': 'N', 'DPV Match Code': 'Y', 'DPV Footnotes': 'AABB', 'General Footnotes': 'L#', 'CMRA': 'N', 'EWS Match': 'default', 'LACSLink Code': 'default', 'LACSLink Indicator': 'default', 'SuiteLink Match': 'default', 'Enhanced Match': 'default'}, 'Components': {'Urbanization': 'default', 'Primary Number': '3301', 'Street Predirection': 'S', 'Street Name': 'Greenfield', 'Street Postdirection': 'default', 'Street Suffix': 'Rd', 'Secondary Designator': 'default', 'Secondary Number': 'default', 'Extra Secondary Designator': 'default', 'Extra Secondary Number': 'default', 'PMB Designator': 'default', 'PMB Number': 'default', 'City': 'Gilbert', 'Default City Name': 'Gilbert', 'State': 'AZ', 'ZIP Code': '85297', '+4 Code': '2176', 'Delivery Point': '01', 'Check Digit': '2'}}
'05'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. Once you create the execute_script, how do you run it to produce the output?

Comment: @swp1 The string passed to `d.execute_script` is executed as Javascript in the `selenium` instance. `route` stores the carrier route, returned from the script.

Comment: Ok. When I run it in my Jupyter notebook , route is the value "default" not "R109". Do you know why it might be doing that?

Comment: @swp1 In your browser's developer console, what is the result of `document.querySelector('#us-street-metadata li:nth-of-type(2) .answer.col-sm-5.col-xs-3')`? In my developer view, the carrier route is the second `li` in the `us-street-metadata`

Comment: In my browser, it's the first item in Metadata (the left most column). The result to that is "default." Is there a way to do find a hypothetical variable? Say you assign a string called column as the value you're looking for. So if column is 'Carrier Route', it finds, the carrier route; if column is 'Congressional District', it finds the Congressional District, and so on.

Comment: That works. Thanks. For some reason, it stores all the values for every value in 'Metadata' dictionary as 'default' for some reason. Out curiosity, does it give you different values whenever you run it, or is it also default for you? If you have a different output, the issue could be with my computer.

Comment: @swp1 Hmm, I am able to produce all non-default values for the visible column keys (i.e Carrier Route). I do get default values, but those are only for hidden fields that are not visible in any of the columns. If you go into the Chrome developer view and run a search for, say, "R109", do any results appear in the Metadata column's source? If not, the issue might have to do with how the search form is submitted.

Comment: If I physically look at the Chrome pop-up, I can see "R109" and the other values, but then it's all default when I run it. Are you using a different web browser?

Comment: @swp1 I am running headless Chrome with `selenium`. Can you post a screenshot/copy of the first 1/4 or 1/3 of the source from the "Metadata" column on your headless browser instance? I would like to see if there are any element structuring differences when compared to mine. Also, a screenshot/source snippet of what you see when you run a search for 'R190' would be helpful as well.

Comment: I included the screenshots in the answer to the question below, since I can't attach them to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax1234, here's the code and screenshot you asked for:

[image]

[image]